# Google Sheets: compare cells and return TRUE/FALSE only if they are not blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is my first question on stackoverflow.

I would like to compare two columns of data on Google Sheets and receive a TRUE/FALSE response (`=A1=B1`) when A1 and B1 are not blank. The simple formula `=A1=B1` gives a TRUE response when comparing two blank cells and a FALSE response if only one of them is blank. My issue is that I would like to receive:

- a N/A response (or any third response but TRUE-FALSE) if *both* are blank;
- a fourth response (could be anything but TRUE-FALSE-N/A) if *only one of the two* is blank.

I tried with the `IF` and `IFS` functions and `not(isblank()` but I got only error messages so far.

Would it be possible to achieve this on Google Sheets?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just simply nest multiple `IF` expressions. Use `COUNTBLANK` to get number of blank cells.

Use the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:B1)=0, A1=B1, IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:B1)=1, "condition4", "condition3"))
```